# In MVVM pattern where data for display be prepared?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-mvvm

Currently I am learing MVVP and trying to create simple app with that pattern. In this application I am using api to fetch some data and in that data there is field with date as string like: `01.01.1999`. Now I would like to display that date in different format, let's say `1 jan 1999`. So my question is if I would like to stay true to MVVM and have good, clean code where that conversion should take place? In my ViewModel or in data provider, before passing the response to ViewModel?

So my idea to do it in ViewModel would be something like:

```
class MyViewModel(private val dataProvider: DataProvider) : ViewModel() {

    var data: MutableLiveData<DisplayData> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getData() {
        dataProvider.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                    onNext = { data -> prepareDataForDisplay(data) })
    }

    fun prepareDataForDisplay(data: Data) {
        data.postValue(DisplayData(data.date.parseToCorrectFormat()))
    }

    data class DisplayData(val date: String)

}
```

Or in my data provider:

```
class DataProvider(private val dataApi: DataApi) {

    override fun getData(): Observable<DisplayData> {
        return dataApi.getData().map { DisplayData(it.date.parseToCorrectFormat()) }
    }

    data class DisplayData(val date: String)
}

interface DataApi {
    @GET("data")
    fun getData(): Observable<Data>
}
```

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is just before applying it to the view (in Fragment, Activity, RecyclerView). If you do this in the repository or viewmodel, when changing the language on the device, the date will be displayed incorrectly.